# Cómo accedo a los valores de un arreglo anidado en angular con typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo el siguiente json que recibo, y quiero usar los valores del arreglo para llenar una tabla, pero no se como hacerlo

Este es el Json que recibo y el arreglo que quiero usar es Data, para usar sus valores en una tabla, los demas datos no me interesan solo los de Data

```
{
"Rowsets": {
    "FechaCreated": "2021-05-04T17:18:52",
    "Version": "15.2 SP3 Patch 7 (Feb 14, 2019)",
    "FechaInicio": "2021-05-04T16:18:52-0500",
    "FechaFinal": "2021-05-04T17:18:52-0500",
    "Destino": "",
    "Row": [
        {
            "Columns": {
                "Column": [
                    {
                        "Name": "prueba",
                        "Source": "2",
                        "Description": "nuevo"
                    }
                   
                ]
            },
            "Data": [
                {
                    "id": "55",
                    "nombre": "pruebas tarea",
                    "descripcion": "auto",
                    "estatus": 1,
                    "fecha": "04/15/2021 09:22:53",
                    "usuario": "luis"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

en mi service tengo esto

```
 return this.httpClient.get
          (this.url).pipe
          (map(rows => rows as Rows));
```

en el component esto

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.monitoresService.getRows().subscribe(m => {
      this.rows = m;
});
}
```

en el module esto

```
export class Rows {

    Rowset: Row[];
   
}

class Row {
    Data: Data[];
    
}

class Data {
    id: string;
    nombre: string;
    descripcion: string;
    estatus: string;
    fecha: string;
    usuario: string;
}
```

no se como llamarla en el html, he llamado datos normales con el ngfor pero no arreglos anidados, me podrían ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones para trabajar con dicho arreglo en el HTML, sería anidar el arreglo don dos etiquetas que contengan el ngFor, y de esta manera te aseguras que si la propiedad "Row" contiene mas de un arreglo, tambien se logre imprimir dentro del template, siguiendo la logica como ya la llevas en tu ngOnInit(), seria algo como esto:

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <div *ngFor="let data of row.Data">
    <p>{{data.id}}</p>
    <p>{{data.nombre}}</p>
    <p>{{data.descripcion}}</p>
    <p>{{data.estatus}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```